# I am using ab as benchmark tool for performance analysis on apache server

Tags: apache, mask, affinity

I am using AB as benchmark tool for performance analysis on apache server.
Is there any way, we can restrict the AB request to specific CPU cores by setting their mask? 
I tried with sched_setaffinity() but it restricts the AB request to a single particular core instead I want to restrict it to specific cores . For examples : If I set mask- 0xf0 CPU cores 2,4,6 get disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific way to do this.

You could do one of the following:

1. Restrict the concurrency level to control CPU usage.
2. Use the operating system to assign the ab process to a particular Core.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `taskset` like

```
taskset x ab -n 100 -c 12 http://localhost/index.html
```

to set the cpu affiinity to a certain core.

`x` is the affinity mask and

```
x = 1 =>core 0
x = 2 =>core 1
x = 4 =>core 2
x = 8 =>core 3
```

Similarly odd numbered values for `x` will enable two or more cores